# Distributing menu items evenly on Actionbar in AppCompat theme

Tags: android, android-layout, android-actionbar, android-menu

I want my action bar to display 5 icons. Since I don't have enough space for displaying main content. So I couldn't use two tabs instead of one. I want the actionbar look like this.  [image: Required Image]
But Instead it looks something like this taking un-necessary space.[image]
I'm not interested in displaying the Appname or app icon. I tried doing several things from stackoverflow but most of them are not working probably because I'm using appcompat theme but android has deprecated the ActionBarActivity so I am bound to use the AppCompat. And most of the answers on stackoverflow works with ActionBarActivity. So, I'm stuck with this problem for last two days

Here's the main Activity

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import com.navdrawer.SimpleSideDrawer;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    private SimpleSideDrawer mNav;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mNav = new SimpleSideDrawer(this);
        mNav.setRightBehindContentView(R.layout.activity_behind_left_simple);



    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        // Inflate the menu items for use in the action bar
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.action_map:
                return true;

            case R.id.action_transport:
                return true;

            case R.id.action_hotel_food:
                return true;

            case R.id.action_travel_more:
                return true;

            case R.id.action_logo:
                mNav.toggleRightDrawer();


            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }

    }
}
```

Menu xml code

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:Journey="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"

    tools:context=".MainActivity">
    <item android:id="@+id/action_map"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_map"
        android:title="@string/action_map"
        Journey:showAsAction="always"/>
    <item android:id="@+id/action_transport"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_transport"
        android:title="@string/action_transport"
        Journey:showAsAction="always"/>
    <item android:id="@+id/action_hotel_food"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_hotel_food"
        android:title="@string/action_hotel_food"
        Journey:showAsAction="always"/>
    <item android:id="@+id/action_travel_more"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_travel_more"
        android:title="@string/action_travel_more"
        Journey:showAsAction="always"/>
    <item android:id="@+id/action_logo"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_logo"
        android:title="@string/action_logo"
        Journey:showAsAction="always"/>

</menu>
```

styles.xml file

```
<resources>

    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    </style>

</resources>
```

Manifest File

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="********" >

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

I'm new to programming and I have a design background. So if the answer is explained with proper codes then that will be very useful. Thanks a lot for help.